# Setting new path for php.ini file

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I was wondering where could I specify new path for php.ini file on Apache2 server running on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you to change the path
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269083/set-path-to-php-ini

These answers bellow was copied from this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the virtual hosts file to point to the new path. You will add a PHPINIDir  directive to the file and then restart Apache -

```
<VirtualHost 2.4.6.8:80>
    PHPINIDir /path/to/php.ini
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to use your virtual host's IP address in the directive.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem Jay.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PHPINIDir path` options in your vhost configuration, for example.

See more info here - http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php