# How to set php.ini location?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp

I just installed PHP, Apache and MySQL, did some changes to the configuration files and it works but phpinfo() says it looks for php.ini in C:\Windows.
How to make it look somewhere else? Should I configure this in Apache? I put:

```
SetEnv PHPRC "C:/wamp/php5.6.5"
```

in http.conf, restared Apache but it didn't help. I know that programs like WampServer use phpForApache.ini instead of php.ini but I don't know how they do this.

Comment: You can find it here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269083/set-path-to-php-ini

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Taken word for word from the docs...](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in order: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z], [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).

Comment: Changing registry is not a good solution, so I went with this option instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269083/set-path-to-php-ini

Comment: As WAMPServer has the ability to switch between many versions of PHP this is NOT a good solution in a WAMPServer environment. Also it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Tom, for future reference, if an answer is not acceptable. Do not accept it.